# How to not expose entities endpoints in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc-openapi-ui

Upgrading my MS from Spring Boot 2.7 to 3.0, i've noticed that entities are exposed even i 'hide' and scan only controller package which contains only APIs,

for an entity **Customer** i could invoke all CRUD actions !

http://localhost:8093/**customer**Entities/7308 GET / PUT /POST

properties ::

```
springdoc:
  paths-to-match: /v1/**
  packages-to-scan: a.b.c.controller // only APIs
```

this could hide entity endpoints from Swagger BUT i could fetch them with url directly.

So how to eliminate those entities endpoint ?

some information :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-common</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.15</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try configuring the *setExposeRepositoryMethodsByDefault* to *false* and check.

Sample code snippet:

```
@Configuration
public class AppRepositoryConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {

        config.setExposeRepositoryMethodsByDefault(false);
    }
}
```